# Unexpected data representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, local-storage

So I have an app, that allows you to add data, and then it displays all the data(still wip). So I made a Create and Read functionality so far using localStorage and jQueryMobile and jQueryUI.

But for some reason when I switch between pages(main page/add data page), I see cloned data on main page. Instead of 2 entries, I see 4 entries, and it's original 2 entries have a copy of each other. And when i refresh the page it's working fine, it displays only original data, without clones. Note that it's only happens when you go to Add page and then returning back to Main page(by clicking Home button).

Also When you are adding a run, for some reason it adding 2 runs at the same time(running add funciton 2 times)

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
  //Display runs
  showRuns();

  //Add Handler for Adding Runs
  $('#submitAdd').on('tap', addRun);

  /*
   * Show all runs on homepage
   */
  function showRuns() {
    //get runs Object
    var runs = getRunsObject();
    var i = 0;

    if (runs != '' && runs != null) {

      for (i; i < runs.length; i++) {
        $('#stats').append('<li class="ui-body-inherit ui-li-static"><strong>Date: </strong>' + runs[i]["date"] + '<strong> <br/>Distnace: </strong>' + runs[i]["kms"] + 'km</li>');
      }

      $('#home').bind('pageinit', function() {
        $('#stats').listview('refresh');
      });

    }
  }

  /*
   * addRun function
   */
  function addRun() {
    //Get form values
    var kms = $('#addKms').val();
    var date = $('#addDate').val();

    //Create 'Run' Object
    var run = {
      date: date,
      kms: parseFloat(kms)
    };

    var runs = getRunsObject();

    //Add run to runs array
    runs.push(run);
    alert('Run Added');

    //Set stringified objects to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('runs', JSON.stringify(runs));

    //Redirect
    window.location.href = "index.php";

    //Preventing form from submiting
    return false;
  }

  /*
   * getRunsObject
   */
  function getRunsObject() {
    //Set runs array
    var runs = [];
    //Get current runs from localStorage
    var currentRuns = localStorage.getItem('runs');

    //Check localStorage
    if (currentRuns != null) {
      //Set to runs
      var runs = JSON.parse(currentRuns);
    }

    //Return sorted runs object
    return runs.sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: block;
}
.controls {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Running Tracker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Main Page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
      <h1>Running Tracker</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home" data-transition="none" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#add" data-transition="none" data-icon="plus">Add Run</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <h3>Welcome to the RunningTracker App</h3>
      <p>
        With this app you can track your running, jogging or walking.
      </p>

      <h3>Your Latest Runs:</h3>

      <ul id="stats" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter runs by date or distance." data-inset="true"></ul>
      <br/>
      <button id="clearRuns" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure?')">
        Clear Data
      </button>
    </div>
    <footer data-role="footer">
      <h4>RunningTracker &copy; 2015 GZ</h4>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Run Page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="add">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
      <h1>Running Tracker</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home" data-transition="none" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#add" data-transition="none" data-icon="plus">Add Run</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <h3>Add Run</h3>
      <form id="addForm">
        <label for="km">Enter Kilometres:</label>
        <input type="number" id="addKms">
        <label for="km">Enter Date:</label>
        <input type="date" data-role="date" class="date" id="addDate" data-inline="true">
        <button id="submitAdd" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">
          Add Run
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <footer data-role="footer">
      <h4>RunningTracker &copy; 2015 GZ</h4>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For some reason example is not loading here on StackOverflow, so here is the live demo:

http://runningtracker.herokuapp.com/index.php

Try adding a new run, and then switch back to the add page, and then back to main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `pageinit` event handling. You are omitting the selector, so the handler is called twice (for `home` and for `add` pages), and in doing so you are calling `$('#submitAdd').on('tap', addRun);` twice, resulting in a double `addRun` call.

Change the line with:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function() {
```

(`pagecreate` now replaces `pageinit`, see [jQM API](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/))

Also, please change your "redirection" removing `window.location.href = "index.php";`.

That instruction changes the page bypassing jQuery Mobile navigation system, with the result of calling `pageinit` event after each `addRun` call (while it should be called only once).

Change your page using the [change](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) method instead:

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "#home", { transition: "none" });
```

Comment: If I replace my redirection with this, it still executes addRun twice, as well as showRuns. So I still have to use one instead of on.

Comment: I haven't pushed your changes yet. I will do it in 1 min. Btw if use your method, $("#results") are not being updated ufter i add new run, I have to reload the page to see them.

Comment: I've pushed the changes.

Comment: Nice, it's almost working now, except the new entry is not being displayed after I add it. I still have to manually reload page to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution. I replaced:

`$(document).on('pageinit', function() {});`

With:

`$(document).one('pageinit', function() {});`

As I understood it, I had 2 pages, so every function was running twice, and it was causing my problems. By using `one` instead of `on` I forced all the scripts to run only once, no matter how many pages I have.